# I do not know why my code wont return an error message I wrote

Tags: php

So I have no clue where I messed up...so I really need help on this. It is pretty annoying also if you guys have any other questions I'll gladly answer them :) And btw the problem is probably in the `if (isset()$POST...etc)` part but I do not know how to fix it...Also you guys do not have to send me the entire code answer a simple answer or a hint would be helpful.

```html
<?php
session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    // ...     
} else {
    if (isset($POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        $usernmae= $_POST['username'];
        $password= $_POST['password'];

        if(empty($username) or empty($password)) {
            $error = 'All fields are required!';
        }
    }
    ?>
    <html>
 <head>
        <title>CMS Tutorial</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/style.css" /> 
 </head>
 <body>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>
            <br/><br /> 
            <?php
            if(isset($error)) {
                ?>
                <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error; ?></small>
                <br /><br />
                <?php
            }
            ?> 

            <form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />      
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Typo: $usernmae= $_POST['username']; - should say username both sides maybe

Comment: I did change it but it still wont work....

Comment: Please update the code in your question to match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the typo at `$usernmae= $_POST['username'];`
Cause you are testing `empty($username)`

And also you need to replace `isset($POST['username'], $_POST['password'])` with `isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])`

(missing the underscore "_" beetween "$" and "POST" for username in your "isset")

Comment: Sorry worked! Fine after you said I was missing the "_" thank you!